# Why am I getting an NA/NaN/Inf in 'y' error in my R code?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, linear-regression

Using the dataset fat in the inbuilt library (faraway), I created a linear model with a logged response (brozek) and the following predictors:

```
library(rafalib)
library(downloader)
library(dplyr)
library(faraway)

brozek <- brozek[ brozek != 0 ]

model <- lm (log(brozek) ~ age + weight + height + neck + chest + abdom + hip + thigh + knee + ankle + biceps + forearm + wrist, data=fat)
summary (model)
```

However, when I run this code, I am getting the following error:

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
```

But when I check if there are any NA or 0 values in brozek:

```
table(is.na(brozek))
any(brozek == 0)
```

I get FALSE.

Where am I getting wrong? Or do I have the completely wrong approach?

Comment: Is this line `brozek <- brozek[ brozek != 0 ]` supposed to be `brozek <- subset(fat, brozek != 0 )` or something? Because `brozek` doesn't exist as a data.frame itself. And then did you intend to pass the `fat` data.frame to `lm()` or this `brozek` subset?

Comment: I changed `brozek <- brozek[ brozek != 0 ]` to `brozek <- subset(fat, brozek != 0 )` but I still get the same error. And I think I intended to pass the `fat` data.frame to `lm()` since all of the predictor variables and the response are from that dataset. I'm a bit new to this, so is my understanding wrong?

Comment: If you just pass the original entire data.frame to `lm`, it's just going to use all the values. It's not going to use the non-zero values that you subsetted. Maybe `fat_no_zero <- subset(fat, brozek != 0)` then `lm(log(brozek) ~ age + weight + ..., data=fat_no_zero)` would make more sense as far as variable names go. Right now you are still including the zeros.